# Trouble in making pen drive bootable for solaris 11.2

Tags: solaris, dual-boot

I am trying to dual boot my system with Windows 8.1 and solaris 11.2.I am using flash drive for making bootable solaris 11.2..But i am not able to create bootable flash drive.

I tried both `.usb` and `.iso` files but none of them worked.I tried UNetBootin for `.iso` image but the flash drive did not became bootable then i tried `.usb`file as instructed [here](http://devzone.sites.pid0.org/OpenSolaris/opensolaris-liveusb-creator)..it was written that the image is written successfully but there was no decrease in size of pen drive and it also dis not became bootable..

How can I use any any of these files (`.usb` and `.iso`) to create a bootable pen drive??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dd` command to make it bootable

```
dd if=<Solaris iso file.iso> of=/dev/sdb
```

Make sure you select as destination the device corresponding to the USB key (/dev/sdb in the above example) and not a partition (such as /dev/sdb1)

For example, this link refers how to make it bootable for [centos](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey)

For solaris, refer this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/documentation/solaris-11-2-faqs-2191871.pdf), to create USB flash drive

Answer (score 0):

Making usb bootable for Solaris from Windows.
Lets go. stop waisting time.

format usb FAT (not FAT32 OR NTFS)

Go http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/install-2245079.html and download x86 usb live media

Go to http://www.osforensics.com/tools/write-usb-images.html an download imageusb & Install imageusb software

After opening imageusb:

1. choose the usb unit you want make bootable
2. SELECT THE ACTION TO BE PERFOMED. Choose option WRITE TO USB DRIVE
3. SELECT THE IMAGE. when browse to find file image choose the extension option ALL FILES to find your file with extension *.usb
4. click WRITE and wait until the process finish.

Thats it.

reboot the computer and if everything went ok you are done.